# Highcharts: how to add a custom action on custom added stock-tools button?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Here is an example code that I have: https://jsfiddle.net/delux123/c9tj1ywa/15/.
Clicking over the button `Alert`, triggers an alert box:

```
function alertMethod() {
  alert("test alert 1");
}
```

Now I wonder if it's possible to add such a custom actions, using the [stock-tools](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/stock-tools)? In the code above, I defined a new button `customAnnotation` in the stock tools

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
  lang: {
    stockTools: {
      gui: {
        customAnnotation: 'Custom action'
      }
    },
    navigation: {
      popup: {
        customAnnotation: 'Action config'
      }
    }
  }
});
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
  ...
  stockTools: {
    gui: {
      enabled: true,
      buttons: [ 'customAnnotation' ],
      definitions: {
        customAnnotation: {
          className: 'highcharts-custom-annotation',
          symbol: 'text.svg'
        },
      }
    }
  },
  navigation: {
    bindings: {
      customAnnotation: {
        start: function(e) {
          alert("test alert 2");
        }
      }
    }
  },
  ...
```

What I want to do is to trigger the `alertMethod` when clicking on this new custom button (in the stock tools). I wonder, is such a customization possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `className` and `init` properies, example:

```
stockTools: {
  gui: {
    enabled: true,
    buttons: ['customAnnotation'],
    definitions: {
      customAnnotation: {
        className: 'highcharts-custom-annotation',
        symbol: 'text.svg'
      },
    }
  }
},
navigation: {
  bindings: {
    customAnnotation: {
      className: 'highcharts-custom-annotation',
      init: function(e) {
        alert("test alert 2");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3s25vq8m/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/navigation.bindings

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by adding the event on chart load:

```
chart: {
  events: {
    load: function() {
        document.querySelectorAll('.highcharts-custom-annotation')[0]
        .addEventListener(
          'click',
          alertMethod
      )
    }
  },
},
```

Full code is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/delux123/c9tj1ywa/22/).